# Why does all the songs in Fucked Up's album "David Comes to Life" consist of three words?

Tags: song-title, backstory

The Canadian hardcore band [Fucked Up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fucked_Up) released the album [David Comes to Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Comes_to_Life) in 2011. The album is formed as a rock opera.

I just noticed that all the songs have *three word titles*. I find it hard to think that it is a coincidence. What is the story behind this, if any?

Below is the track listing:

1. Let Her Rest
2. Queen of Hearts
3. Under My Nose
4. The Other Shoe
5. Turn the Season
6. Running On Nothing
7. Remember My Name
8. A Slanted Tone
9. Serve Me Right
10. Truth I Know
11. Life In Paper
12. Ship of Fools
13. A Little Death
14. I Was There
15. Inside a Frame
16. The Recursive Girl
17. One More Night
18. Lights Go Up

Comment: cos it's their third studio album ?

Comment: @Angst A good idea, though I guess you understand that I am looking for some kind of credible source... My first thought was that it just looks good with only three word song titles.

Comment: Sure, I know any answer has to be from a credible source. All the online reviews I could find about "David Comes to Life" were no help. It seems that FU like themes, but equally they like to leave some things unexplained too.

Comment: @Angst Yeah, I also did research before posting the question. Let's see if anybody knows _anything_ about this. :)